# How runtime weaving works in Spring internally. what is core concept/design behind it

Tags: spring

As we know Spring APO uses Runtime Weaving for weaving aspect and Impl.
how Runtime Weaving is better than compile time and load time weaving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring AOP uses proxies. Dynamic proxies for interfaces can be implemented with the standard JDK. So it's kind of built-in. Proxies for classes can be implemented using CGLIB, which is just a matter of including a library.

This is quite simple compared to the approach AspectJ uses, as it does not require anything special to be done. But it is also limited to aspects around methods, e.g.